# Laravel - Table does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

I create a table with `php artisan make:migration` command. After that i edit the migration file to put the columns and insert standard data.
After i run `php migrate:referesh` command and all good, i go to the database and the table is there with a correct name and data.

In database the table name is rolesStems.

I create a model like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RolesStems extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'value', 'order', 'active','id_stem', 'id_role'];
}
```

And in my controller i do this:

```
use App\RolesStems as RolesStem;   
RolesStem::select('value')->where('active', '=', 1)->where('id_stem', '=', 1)->orderBy('id_role', 'asc')->get());
```

And i have this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.roles_stems' doesn't exist (SQL: select `value` from `roles_stems` where `active` = 1 and `id_stem` = 1 order by `id_role` asc)
```

It put a unknown table name roles_stems, why?

I do this to other table, the same way, but with this table this happens.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you don't follow [Laravel naming conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), you should define table manually:

```
protected $table = 'your_table_name';
```

Comment: Works! Thank you

Comment: Side note: I use the Jeffrey Way Pivot Table extender and it named the table something that caused this problem. https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

Answer (score 6):

For table with the name `rolesStems` your `model` must have the name `RolesStem`

So change the following line:

```
class RolesStems extends Model
```

to

```
class RolesStem extends Model
```

**This is the default Laravel naming convention**: [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models)

If you don't want to follow this naming convention, then put the following code in your model:

```
protected $table = 'your_table_name';
```

So that your model refers to `your_table_name`

Comment: I just started using this framework and took me a minute to realise what was happening but no obvious way to resolve this without having to google - this framework seems like it's very "if you know you know" but thanks for explaining this

Comment: Check the documentation, everything is available there.

Answer (score 2):

@user3242861, By default Laravel Try to find table according to Your Model Class name eg: your class "RolesStems" then it will try to find table "roles_stems" so if it is not available then it will give table or view not exists.

To override default functionality you can define table name explicitly in your model class as below.

```
protected $table = 'your_table_name';
```